# Action of the Picard Scheme of an Elliptic Fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, rational-points, elliptic-surfaces

Suppose that we have a surface $X$ defined over a field $k$ (I am interested in $k$ being a number field) and an elliptic fibration $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$, i.e. $f$ is proper and almost all fibres are smooth curves of genus 1. Let $U \subset \mathbb{P}^1$ be the subset of points above which the fibre of $f$ is smooth. We have the following result from *"Néron Models" (Bosch, Lütkebohmert, Raynaud)* [Prop. 4, p. 260]:

**Proposition:** Let $f: X \rightarrow S$ be a proper smooth morphism of schemes whose geometric fibres are connected curves. Then $\textrm{Pic}_{X/S}^0$ is an abelian $S$-scheme and there is a canonical $S$-ample rigidified line bundle $\mathscr{L}\left(X/S\right)$ on $\textrm{Pic}_{X/S}^0$.

In particular, denoting $X|_U = f^{-1}\left(U\right)$, we have that $f: X|_U \rightarrow U$ satisfies the hypotheses of the proposition, and so, denoting the associated Picard scheme $\textrm{Pic}_{X|_{U}/U}^0$ by $G$, we have that $G$ is an abelian group scheme over $U$.

I would like to show that $X$ is a $U$-torsor under $G$. Then it only remains to produce an action of $G$ on $X$ for which the map

$Y \times_X G \rightarrow Y \times_X Y, \quad \left(y,g\right) \mapsto \left(y, yg\right)$

is an isomorphism (so, roughly speaking, given a point $u \in U$, the fibre of the structure morphism of $G$ above $u$ acts freely and transitively on the fibre of $f$ above $u$). Here I am using the definition of a torsor relative to some base scheme as given in *"Torsors and Rational Points", (Skorogobatov)* [Def. 2.2.1, p. 13] (we also have to verify that $f$ is fppf, but I think this follows quite readily).

**So, is there such an action of $G = \textrm{Pic}_{X|_{U}/U}^0$ on $X|_{U}$?**

While a lot is said in *"Néron Models"* about the representability of the relative Picard functor, I still am not quite sure of the explicit structure of the scheme that represents it when it is representable, and so I am not sure how I might define such an action. I think, therefore, that I need to understand what this scheme actually "looks like" (although I haven't ruled out that there may be some way to employ the functor which this scheme represents to derive this action).

In addition to being told that this result is known to some, it is also a natural relative generalisation of the action of the Jacobian on a curve of genus 1, so I really do think this should hold. Any advice offered on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Disclaimer: I am relatively new to research, so I apologise for any oversight I might have made in asking this question. However, I have been unable to find a treatment of this topic in the literature, and at the same time, as I said above, I have been told that results on this topic are known.

Comment: Representing the Picard functor actually gives a group scheme $Pic_{X|_U}$ over $U$ (not of finite type) whose identity component is $Pic^0_{X|_U}$. $X|_U$ itself can be naturally identified with $Pic^1_{X|_U}$ (the open subscheme corresponding to line bundles of fibrewise degree $1$) and then the action you are looking for is simply the action of $Pic^0$ on $Pic^1$ coming from the group structure on $Pic$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. However, I am not quite clear on how this identification of $X|_U$ with $\textrm{Pic}_{X|_U}^1$ takes place. As is my understanding, to obtain the relative Picard functor $\textrm{Pic}_{X/S}$, we sheafify the contravariant functor from $S$-schemes to sets defined by $\textrm{P}_{X/S}\left(T\right) = \textrm{Pic}\left(X \times_S T\right)$. Couldn't this sheafification make the identification you mention a problem? At any rate, if you could please explain how to make this identification, I would be very grateful.

Comment: There is a natural morphism from $X|_U$ to $Pic^1(X|_U)$ given by sending any $S$ valued point of $X|_U$, i.e. a section of the map $X|_U \times_U S$ to $S$ (which gives a Cartier divisor on $X$) to the associated line bundle. One can check that this morphism is an isomorphism by using that it is true fibrewise. (A good reference for the Picard functor is the book "Neron models" by Bosch, Luetkebohmert and Raynaud.)

Comment: Ah, that's great! I think I understand now. Thanks again for your explanation.